# Symmetric monoidal structure of the heart of $S^1$-spectra

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy-category

How to give a symmetric monoidal structure of $SH^{S^1}(k)^{\heartsuit}$ (after $\mathbb{A}^1$-localization)? The standard answer is
$$E_1\otimes E_2:=(E_1\wedge E_2)_{[0,0]}$$
but I don't see why truncation functors are compatible with smash products.

Comment: I don't know about the case you're interested in, but for usual spectra and usual chain complexes, you need the LHS to be a smash product over $H\mathbb Z$ ( or $Hk$ if your chain complexes are over $k$) - is that not something that would matter here ?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Here the smash product is between spectra of simplicial sheaves (of sets), not simplicial abelian sheaves.

Comment: @NanjunYang: The smash product is defined for spectra of simplicial sheaves of sets.

Comment: For the new version of your question, you may reduce to connective objects (objects of $\mathscr C_{\geq 0}$, $\mathscr C$ being your stable $\infty$-category. So you only need to prove the following : if $E$ is connective, and $f$ is a $0$-equivalence between connective objects, then so i $E\otimes f$. Again, I don't know your specific situation so I don't know how easy that is, but it may be good to know that this suffices. If your smash product is sufficiently nice (which I assume it is), it suffices to show that connective objects are stable under tensor product

Comment: What I call $\otimes$ in my previous comment is what you call $\wedge$

Comment: @MaximeRamzi I've understood that $(HM\wedge HN)_{\leq 0}=H(M\otimes N)$.